# Best way of representing Hierarchical data in android

Tags: android, hierarchy

I am trying to find out the best way of representing hierarchical data in android. There are no tree view controls and expandable list views dont work since i can have many levels of hierarchy. I thought I could use the Pulse app view to show data but again that is customised for one level. How best both visually and implementation wise then can I represent hierarchy in android for n levels ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple patterns you can use here; I would recommend looking at the following articles for ideas:

- [Designing Effective Navigation: Descendant and Lateral Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html), specifically the discussion of tabs and lists/grids/stacks/carousels. I'd also look at horizontal paging (swipe views).
- [Android Design: App Structure Pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html)

Comment: Tx. I am using a view pager with tabs + scrollable lists to cut down on hierarchy and display as much data as possible in a single screen. But the prob I have is my top level pager tab grouping might change from one rendition of the app to another. So I feel this will create a confusion to the user. For instance I might have animal, bird, reptile in one rendition and aves, sapiens and plants in another. Is this confusion a real concern? Or are there apps that you know off like this. Also wht pattern is the CNN app(Also what pattern is the CNN app( http://goo.gl/heoof ) using for the menu?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'rendition' of the app, can you elaborate? The CNN app is effectively using scrollable tabs: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Comment: Rendition here implies different versions of the app if you will - I have one apk which will allow me to download content based on what I need. If I need to study about animals/birds, I ll download that content and the tabs become animal,bird,reptile. But if i want to download content about plants I ll download that and my tabs become aves/sapiens/plants(context sensitive menu if you will). I hope you get what I am trying to say. This is only an example(or a lack of it).

Comment: Ah I see. If you must have a potentially very deep or very dynamic information hierarchy, you may need to stick to drilldown navigation, or somehow annotate/curate your hierarchy when the app fetches the data indicating what kind of UI element to use.

Comment: :) yeah I figured. The problem I have is not only is the hierarchy dynamically increasing but the visual appeal of the app also has to be maintained. List views with drill downs are not for me - hence I am creating my own horizontal visual lists.This way im cutting down on hierarchy by a factor of 2. Thanks!

Comment: But I cant seem to find a single place which can guide me to developing scrollable tabs with arrows for navigating. All the related stackoverflow questions seem to be unanswered. Can you guide me to the right location if you can please.

Comment: @Vrashabh `PagerTitleStrip` from the support package will do this, but it doesn't have arrows (arrows are no longer needed per our visual design spec for scrollable tabs). You can also copy the code and mess with it if it doesn't exactly suit your needs.

Comment: But that is for a view pager right - I already have horizontal swipe lists in my app - adding a view pager to swipe between categories will totally confuse the user - so I am only looking for clickable buttons with arrows in the strip. I am looking at gallery with text views as buttons . But gallery centers the views - i need them to maintain positions on clicks. Is there a way to achieve that - or I am just going to have to use a horizontal scroll view and add buttons dynamically and not find a workaround to use an adapter along with it ?

Comment: I gotcha... HorizontalScrollView is generally better for this than Gallery.

Comment: But HorizontalScrollViews have no adapter capabilities - I need my data coming from a database - thats why I thought of a gallery - but gallery is a beast on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your responses and patience. I pretty much have everything I need

Answer (score 11):

Drilldown navigation:
[image]

See also:

- http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html
- http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/drill-down-navigation

---

**Update:**

1) Add location breadcrumbs at the top of the screen to indicate where in the hierarchy you are.

[image]

2) Don't let the new level cover the previous level.  Let some pixels of each level be reachable.  In this example you can just let the menu icons and the profile pictures (from the first two levels) be visible.

[image]

Comment: Android phone settings would be a good example here.

Comment: @Jorn Thanks! This was what I initially built and rejected because
a. I can have 6 levels of hierarchy
Drill downs can become really painful
b. I want to visually represent data in a way it stands out 
c. And I am building a tablet app so there is more room to work with. 
Can you think of better ways to do this.

Comment: Also I am trying to display data at one single glance as much as possible.

Comment: I still believe that this approach would work fine.  As @Roger mentions, "Android setting" is a good example.  You can also try for yourself with a Dropbox app (https://www.dropbox.com/android).  In Dropbox you can browse several levels represented by folders.  I have two additional suggestions to make the drilldown navigation better.  1) Add location breadcrumbs to indicate where in the hierarchy you are.  2) Don't let the new level cover the previous level entirely, but let the leftmost part of each level be reachable (eg: MyPad).  I'll update my answer to clarify with some examples.

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit: Yes, [Miller columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) are the solution. However, [pure Adnroid rejects end-of-line carets](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) (last item on the page), which is a rather strange decision but, nonetheless, it's the appropriate design pattern.

Comment: +1 for the breadcrumbs - i was half way into implementing it with breadcrumbs when i saw this . Thanks! But the different levels im doing a combination of view pager and horizontal scrollable lists - dunno if that is a design pattern - but it seems to best represent what I am trying to do