# N-level tree structure in android

Tags: layout, android, hierarchy

I have a list of categories and subcategories and items under each category individually and also items under the subcategories. I would want to display this in a sliding layer , such that it only occupies a certain portion of the screen, with the main screen still visible.

I have looked at the expandable list view and also [tree-node structure](https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/source/browse) and also gone through [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17703/best-way-of-representing-hierarchical-data-in-android)

I even tried implementing my own expandable listview that extended to n-levels , was successful too but then the situations changed now. I was using POJO classes that had the relationships defined inside them that is subcategories iterating through the category POJO. But i am now using a cursor. It is possible to use cursors with expandable listviews, but never tried with n-level expandable list view. It would un-necessarily increase the number of queries to be made.

Could i have some clue as to where to begin from? The tree-node example is good but then it has the parent levels and all defined before head, while in my case, it may vary . multiple panels will not suit the requirement since multiple clicks and also space has to be considered.

Comment: Targetting Android mobile?

Comment: currently yes just the android mobile..

Comment: Perhaps you could rephrase your questions with screenshot examples? Not quite sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a similar problem one way of solving this is with spinners.

[image]

This screenshot doesn't actually explain entirely what I mean; what I'm thinking you could do instead is something like this:

```
[spinner](category) - default is all

on click the sub-category appears below and you can simply dive deeper.

[spinner](subcategory)


[SUBMIT BUTTON]  the button to perform the action should always be present, 
to allow the user to go through at anytime; of course you could toggle the state 
to force the user to hit a certain level
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply :).. Yes, i tried it with spinners too, i do get the solution, and +1 for this answer cz i know it works, but i seem to be a little keen on expandable listview and tree view,since in the case of spinners, i have to maintain the stack or something of the same to identify if its the category spinner currently in the view or if its the sub_item spinner, and if sub-item spinner i need to keep track of the levels its reached,since this is all about n-level :)